# Devise + Switch User : How to avoid trackable update for a switch user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, switch-user

I am using [switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user) rails gem to login as any other devise user from an admin account. When I use switch_user for an account, the devise session updates all the devise trackable attributes for that user such as:

```
t.integer  "sign_in_count",                 
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
```

which I don't want to happen. These updates should happen only when an end user actually logs in and not for an admin account through switch_user.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Any help on this will be greatly appreciated!